# Is there an Ubuntu MIDI synthesizer program which takes MIDI input and plays to current audio output without complex setup?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, alsa, jack, midi

I have an old M-audio KeyRig 49 USB keyboard.  I know that it works with the [following test](https://sndrtj.eu/2019/10/19/Using-a-USB-midi-keyboard-on-Ubuntu/):

```
$ aconnect -i
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
    0 'Timer           '
    1 'Announce        '
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'
client 24: 'KeyRig 49' [type=kernel,card=2]
    0 'KeyRig 49 MIDI 1'

$ aseqdump -p 24
Waiting for data. Press Ctrl+C to end.
Source  Event                  Ch  Data
  0:1   Port subscribed            129:1 -> 130:0
 24:0   Note on                 9, note 96, velocity 20
 24:0   Note off                9, note 96
```

I have my Ubuntu connected to a Bluetooth speaker.  MIDI synthesizer websites like [this one](https://musescore.com/user/40853685/scores/8269487) play fine through the speaker.  However, when I look for instructions to download a MIDI synthesizer composition app, I see very complicated instructions like [this one](https://sndrtj.eu/2019/10/19/Using-a-USB-midi-keyboard-on-Ubuntu/), and after I'm done, the app doesn't play through my Bluetooth.  These instructions involve knowing details of jack, pcmaudio, etc. and are very daunting.

Is there a synthesizer program I can download on Ubuntu that "just works", in the sense that the [MuseScore website](https://musescore.com/user/40853685/scores/8269487) "just works" to play synthesizer output through Bluetooth (or whatever audio output currently works for Youtube etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my purpose (helping my daughter practice cello) I needed a free Ubuntu synthesizer that works with my old M-Audio KeyRig 49 USB midi controller, plays to my Bluetooth speaker, and produces Cello.  I got this sorted.

The answer is [VMPK](https://vmpk.sourceforge.io/).  For the Midi connections, I set this to ALSA for input and [SonivoxEAS](https://github.com/pedrolcl/Linux-SonivoxEas) for output.  I don't recall doing anything to get SonivoxEAS, it was just there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works for me to play MIDI files in Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS with VLC (via apt) and FluidSynth.

```
sudo apt install vlc
sudo apt install vlc-plugin-fluidsynth
```

and then run

```
vlc file.mid
```

---

- If VLC is already launched you may need to turn it off and start it again after installing `vlc-plugin-fluidsynth`.
- I could not make the snap version of VLC to play MIDI files.

Comment: Hi @sudodus, the question is not to play out to a MIDI synth device, it is to find a MIDI soft synthesizer which takes my old MIDI keyboard as an input, and produces sounds on my Bluetooth speaker.

Comment: @LarsEricson, Sorry for the misunderstanding. Do you want me to delete the answer, or do you want it to stay here, even if it is not useful for you? Unfortunately, I cannot help you, but with some luck, someone else might find your question, and the chances increase, if you edit your question (maybe add some minor detail or explanation).

Comment: You can leave it up, it may help someone.  I will answer the question myself because I finally got a solution.